# Translation of the Zero-Clause BSD License into Esperanto

Tags: translation

I would like to translate the [Zero-Clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/license/0bsd/) into Esperanto so that more people can understand what the license says. I used AI to translate the text roughly, and I tried to revise it.

*Postscript on 2024-03-25:
I have put the translation on [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/septsea/permesiloj) (and here is [a mirror](https://gitee.com/septsea/permesiloj)). The translation below is out of date. There are also other two licenses which I have translated into Esperanto.*

What do you think of the translation (or the translations, if you wish to comment on the translations of other licenses [there](https://github.com/septsea/permesiloj))? Thank you.

---

Here is the text which I want to translate into Esperanto. *Words written in italic* are notes, and are not translated.

> *(The paragraph below is not part of the license.)*
> This software is made available under the Zero-Clause BSD License. Here is an **unofficial** translation of the license into Esperanto. It is provided to help more people understand the license. It was not published by the author of the license, and **does not** legally state the distribution terms for a software that uses the license—only the original English text of the license does that.
>
> *(Here is the license. "Determinantulo" is just one of my pseudonyms.)*
> Copyright © 2024 Determinantulo
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.
>
> *(The original version of the following paragraph is in capital letters: THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS".... I changed the format to make the text easier to read.)*
> **The software is provided "as is" and the author disclaims all warranties with regard to this software including all implied warranties of merchantability and fitness. In no event shall the author be liable for any special, direct, indirect, or consequential damages or any damages whatsoever resulting from loss of use, data or profits, whether in an action of contract, negligence or other tortious action, arising out of or in connection with the use or performance of this software.**

Here is my attempt.

> Ĉi tiu programaro estas havebla laŭ la Nul-Kondiĉa Permesilo de BSD. Jen **neoficiala** traduko de la permesilo en Esperanton. Ĝi estas provizita por helpi pli da homoj kompreni la permesilon. Ĝi ne estis publikigita de la aŭtoro de la permesilo, kaj **ne** laŭleĝe deklaras la distribukondiĉojn por programaro, kiu uzas la permesilon—nur la originala angla teksto de la permesilo faras tion.
>
> Aŭtorrajto © 2024 Determinantulo
>
> Permeso uzi, kopii, modifi kaj/aŭ distribui ĉi tiun programaron por iu ajn celo kun aŭ sen pago estas ĉi tie donita.
>
> **La programaro estas provizita "tiel, kiel estas", kaj la aŭtoro ne donas iujn ajn garantiojn rilate al ĉi tiu programaro, inkluzive de ĉiuj implicitaj garantioj pri merkatkapableco kaj taŭgeco. En neniu okazo la aŭtoro estu respondeca pri iuj ajn specialaj, rektaj, nerektaj, aŭ konsekvencaj damaĝoj aŭ iaj ajn damaĝoj rezultantaj el perdo de uzado, datumoj aŭ profitoj, ĉu en ago de kontrakto, neglektado aŭ alia delikta ago, sekvantaj el aŭ rilataj al la uzado aŭ rendimento de ĉi tiu programaro.**

What do you think of the translation? Thank you.